# Eclipse with ROS

Tags: rosnode, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros-electric.

Already, I have many built packages. In between, I thought its better to have debugger with GUI. So, I have an idea of using eclipse. I followed the page: http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs. If I need to use eclipse for an already built project, Shall I built the same project in the same directory once again or how to do it for the already built project (the already built project is without using eclipse)?

thanks in advance for you answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46795/eclipse-with-ros/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-10-25

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-10-27**:
-1 for asking the same question as a comment to [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/10091/eclipse-debugging-in-ros/#14792). Asking the same question twice means duplicated work for people who answer them.

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-10-28**:
But I asked this question, before commenting the answer. Nobody answered this question for a day. So, What to do no other go..

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-10-29**:
Be a little more patient next time. Ola answered you question, didn't he? Or at least instead of copy-pasting your question into a comment, just link to that question in the comment.

Anyhow, I was just a little annoyed that I basically wrote the same thing that Ola wrote when I saw this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use Eclipse for the packages that you have built without Eclipse, just import them as described at http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#Importing_the_project_into_Eclipse. You do not have to write your code in new packages just because you are using an IDE.

---

Originally posted by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) with karma: 328 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4